# how can I solve "Index out of bounds error"?

Tags: java

I use this key as 3DES key to exchange with RSA--->
**private static final byte[] MY_KEY = "5oquil2oo2vb63e8ionujny6l9k8".getBytes();**

```
public byte[] encrypt_des(String message) throws Exception {
       byte[] encrypted = RSA.this.encrypt(MY_KEY);
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(RSA.this.encrypt(MY_KEY));
   final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    for (int j = 0, k = 1; k < encrypted.length;) {
       keyBytes[k++]=keyBytes[j++];
    }

    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    // final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
    // .encode(cipherText);

    return cipherText;
}
```

And this error appears at the output--->
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 24 out of bounds for length 24
at RSA.encrypt_des(RSA.java:100)
at RSA.main(RSA.java:62)**.
How can I solve this error ? and how can I i use encrypted/decrypted key from RSA in 3DES (this method above)?

Comment: It  means that it is time to use your debugger

Comment: An array of 24 positions can only use index values from 0 to 23.  I suspect your for loop is set up incorrectly.

Comment: i use it but i can't get a result

Comment: How can i use encrypted key in RSA in 3DES ?